# org babel tangle file without main function

Tags: c++, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am using the fantastic org-babel package for emacs.

I want to generate some code WITHOUT the main function in it for C++ code,
but I cannot figure out how to do it.

```
#+begin_src C++ :tangle MyClass.h
namespace ns {
    class MyClass {};
}
#+end_src
```

This will generate:

```
int main() {
    namespace ns {
       class MyClass {};
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can instruct org-babel to not generate a main function?
I could not find any documentation or hint anywhere.

Any alternative that lets me inline the code in the org file and tangle it without evaluation
would be a solution too for my current problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So I found how to do it in the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-C.html#orgca44b07), finally:

:main
can be set to "no" to inhibit wrapping of the code block in a main function call.

```
#+begin_src C++ :main no
//Code goes here
#+end_src
```

This will do it.